# Trivial flag with vote restrictions

Tags: discussion

While reviewing a couple of discussions on meta regarding quality of posts, one thought came to mind to help prevent vote harvesting by offering solutions to simple questions which inherently garner more upvotes disproportionately from questions of a more complex nature. Reference: *[Is it OK for Stack Exchange to treat all questions / answers equally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104422/is-it-ok-for-stack-exchange-to-treat-all-questions-answers-equally)*

The idea, would be rather trivial to implement:

Add a new option at the bottom of the question on the same line as "close", "delete", etc. that is clearly visible called "trivial" to mark the question as a trivial question.

The result, (in my opinion), could have an effect on the questions, limiting the reputation gain from the questions and answers.

Likewise, there could be a "complex" option as well, which would boost the reputation gain of votes.

I feel something like this would help to balance the reputation gains and garner more interest from those who are savvy into the more complex questions as they would have a higher reward ceiling, where trivial questions would have a cap.

What do you think are the pros or cons to this?

Comment: Every question is trivial when the right expert is looking at it. Can you define what you consider "trivial"?

Comment: @Tunaki - true enough, it is objectionable depending on skill level.  I was speaking merely about what the author of the linked post posts as suggestions of trivial type questions. I expect this will likely not be favorable among those who have used the stated tactic to garner rank, however I propose this as it could lend to a more balanced system where the easy questions aren't as attractive as the complex questions.  The community would of course vote if the question is complex or easy by the links I suggest.  No selection would keep it as a normal question.

Comment: I think that attempting to limit votes on "trivial" questions comes from envy/jealousy (I don't say I about you BTW). The questions got upvotes because they are there helping you when you Google an error and fined them just when you need it. The asker was there at the right time to ask a specific question that was answered by another user, which helped along the years to hundreds of other users. So I say - Let them enjoy their deserved credit

Comment: Generally trivial questions can be closed as dupes as most likely there it has already been asked and answered.  If not then why get rid of it?  It will help the next person that has the same lack of basic understanding/can be used as a dupe target.  This may also be solved with a possible close to Docs example.

Comment: @AlonEitan - true, it may seem a bit unfair at first for those "How do I declare a variable in c#" questions,  but is that questions answer really worth more than something which took hours to solve and reply which would garner very little response due to it's complexity ?

Comment: @NathanOliver - a closed question still gets votes.  I am sure that this has been abused to garner rep for alt accounts or buddies.  due to them still showing in google for some time, that is sufficient to get a rep boost for something like "I am geting an exception and can't fix it" with "int x = 1 / 0;".  That really shouldn't gain any rep for any answers imho, but I am saying we can extend a little rep, but just cap it. Questions that the community decides requires actual thought, should definitely gain more rep. As it stands, this is not balanced.

Comment: The imbalance causes more people to pay attention to trivial questions, and in turn those questions get higher rank, due to how simple they are, where a lot of more complex questions receive few if any votes or visits.  Wouldn't it make sense to reward the more intelligent solutions with a greater proportion than the zero thought required solutions ?

Comment: @SanuelJackson In those days, no - Users asking such questions should get massively downvoted and closed, and if they keep asking low quality questions they should get a question ban. Usually those trivial questions are usually 5+ years old

Answer (score 12):

**Absolutely not.** Besides arguably going counter to the purpose of reputation on SE, this would be horribly, horribly open to abuse and create lots of strife for no gain (Why are you trying to deny people rep? For what?)

This would:

- Cause answerers to "trivial" questions to complain about that classification, or not understand
- Not take into account that what is trivial for someone isn't for someone else
- Be usable as a weapon to deny rep to someone you don't like
- Generate resentment among answerers
- Make it significantly less likely for "trivial" questions to get answered.
- Be essentially a crapshoot since what any two members of the community consider "trivial" could be highly different.

> I feel something like this would help to balance the reputation gains
>   and garner more interest from those who are savvy into the more
>   complex questions as they would have a higher reward ceiling, where
>   trivial questions would have a cap.

Most likely it would instead get trivial questions significantly less answered, get abused to all hell, and incite a permanent meta war over the official definition of "trivial".

Comment: As it would be community driven, the votes for trivial or complex would not be based on any single persons review, and would work the same way question reviews happen now.  Option in review mode, as well as to the users who visit the question.   A loss of answers for trivial questions, for more answers to the more complex questions would balance the system. There would still be those answering simple questions, and those who have moved on to answer more complex ones.

Comment: @SanuelJackson But then again, if it's community-driven it could abused horribly. If you have a network of rep-greedy people, and more than one have access to review and they all click trivial, that'd be abused. You can't fix a problem with another. Besides, rep is just an imaginary point system-why limit others?